# Microsoft source code annotation language (SAL) does not give C26100 or other warnings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, annotations, sal

I am trying to see if SAL can be used to detect concurrency bugs. I prepared a project according to [Sample C++ project for code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/demo-sample?view=msvc-170) and tried the sample code on [Code analysis for C/C++ warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/code-analysis-for-c-cpp-warnings?view=msvc-170).

However, I am not getting the warnings that should appear in some of the sample codes.　Specifically, C26100, C26101、C26110、C26111、C26112、C26115、C2611 and C26140　get warnings, but C26105, C26116, C26130, C26135, C26160, C26165, C26166 and C26167 do not.

For C26105, we tried the following code on [C26105](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26105?view=msvc-170)

```
#include <sal.h>
#include <Windows.h>

_Create_lock_level_(MutexLockLevel);
_Create_lock_level_(TunnelLockLevel);
_Create_lock_level_(ChannelLockLevel);
_Lock_level_order_(MutexLockLevel, TunnelLockLevel);
_Lock_level_order_(TunnelLockLevel, ChannelLockLevel);
_Has_lock_level_(MutexLockLevel) HANDLE gMutex;

struct Tunnel
{
    _Has_lock_level_(TunnelLockLevel) CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
};

struct Channel
{
    _Has_lock_level_(ChannelLockLevel) CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
};

void OrderInversion(Channel* pChannel, Tunnel* pTunnel)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&pChannel->cs);
　　　　　　　　// I expect Warning C26105, but no warning.
    WaitForSingleObject(gMutex, INFINITE);
    EnterCriticalSection(&pTunnel->cs);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&pTunnel->cs);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&pChannel->cs);
}
```

Why is this? If you have any information, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

My environment is as follows.

- Windows 10 Pro 21H2 19044.1826
- Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.2.6

Comment: You  can  report the problem to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=62) and post the link here.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have reported the problem to Developer Community.

Answer (score 0):

1.Set the Code Analysis rules: `Microsoft All rules` in properties.

[image]

2.Enable  Code Analysis on Build:Yes
[image]

Error List:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information. However, I changed the Code Analysis rules to `Microsoft All rules` and still did not get the warning.

Comment: Hi,@minguu42  I updated answer. Enable Code Analysis on Build:Yes

Comment: Thanks @Minxin Yu - MSFT for the additional information. I have tried that and no warning is given. [Issue is up in the developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/SAL-annotations-does-not-give-C26100-or/10112284) and current status is Under Consideration.